# Robocopy unable to distinguish destination from source

Tags: robocopy

I am using a robocopy batch file to backup my work. This is the code in my .bat file:

```
@echo off
cls
echo press any key to continue backup!
pause
ROBOCOPY "F:\source" "D:\destination" /s /e /xf *.sas7bdat /xd "F:\directory_to_exclude"
echo backup complete
pause
```

However this does not work and the log output shows that robocopy does not distinguish the destination from the source.

```
Source: F:\source D:\destination
Dest -
Files *.*
Files excluded: *.sas7bdat
Directories excluded: F:\directory_to_exclude
---------------------------------------------
Error: no folder destination specified
```

What needs to be changed in the robocopy syntax?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Possible problem is that your source or/and destination ends by `\`. So you have that sequence of characters `\"`, and `robocopy` interpret it as escape sequence for literal `"`. You have to remove `\` or double it:

```
ROBOCOPY "F:\source" "D:\destination"
ROBOCOPY "F:\source\\" "D:\destination\\"
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! I have done so much to dance around this problem for years by always using paths that didn't need quotes on them. Thank-you, thank-you, thank-you! Now the question is why isn't this noted in the Robocopy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your Robocopy output mentions both source and destination paths on the Source: line. Are you sure you quoted the command right?

I copied just the robocopy command and here is my output:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Thursday, March 26, 2015 9:48:44 AM
   Source - F:\source\
     Dest - D:\destination\

    Files : *.*

Exc Files : *.sas7bdat

 Exc Dirs : F:\directory_to_exclude

  Options : *.* /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I (double)quote the source and destination wrong I get the following result (like yours):

```
   Source - F:\source D:\destination\
```

Comment: My bat file uses `"` as quotation marks. Changing them to `'`does not work either and lists the source as `F:\ F:\source\'\` and destination as `F:\ D:\destination\'\` and fails because it can't find these directories as they don't exist.

Comment: If your source folder is called source and if your destination folder is actually called destination try to remove the quotation marks since there are no spaces in the foldernames.

Comment: Thanks, spaces exist in the real folder names but adding a double slash as PetSerAl mentions solves the problem.